# result returns just new line \n not whats printed after command is run

Tags: terminal, command-line

Ultimately I'm trying to catch some errors that are popping up but aren't getting returned.

Here's the command I'm trying to run.

```
/usr/bin/dscl . -change /Users/admin NFSHomeDirectory /Users/admin /var/admin
```

when it runs successfully it returns \n
when it comes up with an error I get \n and

```
<main> attribute status: eDSAttributeNotFound
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -13134 (eDSAttributeNotFound)
```

I know why I'm getting the error and I'm actually making it happen intentionally so that I can (hopefully) get terminal to write the next two lines out to a file or (eventually) send it using CURL to another computer.

So when I run the command with either > tomytextfile.txt it writes and empty file or using my POST request like so

```
echo "result=`/usr/bin/dscl . -change /Users/admin NFSHomeDirectory /Users/admin /var/admin`" | curl --data-urlencode result@- http://172.16.26.251:8080/script
```

I get this as the response on the server where I'm sending the curl POST request.

```
{ result: 'result=\n' }
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be super grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing `> tomytextfile.txt` with `> tomytextfile.txt 2>&1`.

Similarly, you could use what is shown below.

```
echo "result=`/usr/bin/dscl . -change /Users/admin NFSHomeDirectory /Users/admin /var/admin 2>&1`" | curl --data-urlencode result@- http://172.16.26.251:8080/script
```

Basically, `2>&1` redirects error output to regular output.

Comment: Yup, That worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help.